# Error Huobi Api "err-code": "api-signature-not-valid", "err-msg": "Signature not valid: Incorrect Access key [Access key\u9519\u8bef]"

Tags: python, api, request, huobi

I have the following code:

```html
import hmac
import hashlib
import json
import time
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import requests

access_key = 'cb3e8274-bg2rg65tmn-02ar6g57-c7a5'
secret_key = '365ca06e-72fege10-f11218c6-1423f'

def sign(secret_key, data):
    digest = hmac.new(bytes(secret_key, 'utf-8'), bytes(data, 'utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
    return digest.hex()

params = {
    'AccessKeyId': access_key,
    'SignatureMethod': 'HmacSHA256',
    'SignatureVersion': '2',
    'Timestamp': time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()),
}

query_string = urlencode(sorted(params.items()))

signature = sign(secret_key, f"GET\napi.huobi.pro\n/v1/query/deposit-withdraw\n{query_string}")

params['Signature'] = signature

url = f"https://api.huobi.pro/v1/query/deposit-withdraw?{query_string}&Signature={signature}"

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()

with open('wHuobi.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Но после успешного выполнения кода в файле wHuobi.json высвечивается ошибка:
`{"status": "error", "err-code": "api-signature-not-valid", "err-msg": "Signature not valid: Incorrect Access key [Access key\u9519\u8bef]", "data": null}`

I searched the internet for a solution, but the solution was different for everyone and not in Python